# Css - Select label far from input

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a selector that let me style a label that's not near the respective input

Html

```
<article>
 <header>
  <label for="view-today-node-0">VIEW</label>
 </header>

 <input type="radio" name="view-today-node" id="view-today-node-0" />
</article>
```

I need to style the label when the radio is checked.

Something similar to

```
article  input[type="radio"]:checked + label {}
```

but the label is not near the input

Comment: CSS probably can't do this but your HTML is not adequate to diagnose properly. Why would the label not be next to the input?

Comment: This can't be done (as yet) with CSS, you'll need to use JavaScript I'm afraid; though it seems you're looking for the [reference (`/ref/`) combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#idref-combinators), from CSS level 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the general sibling combinator (`~`) to style the label if it is not next to the input, but still a sibling:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    color:green;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EPHXU/

Comment: I use this for showing the content near the input radio, but it must be a sibling. I have moved the label to test a better view but I guess I'll have to wait a while :/

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery-Solution:**

```
$("label[for='view-today-node']").css('background','#F00');
```

Comment: Why is it a 'bad' solution? Admittedly it uses a JavaScript library, rather than plain JavaScript, but JS *is* the only way this can be done.

Comment: Any reasons for calling this bad? It's simply not possible doing this by CSS fully functionally. There's no corresponding selector. What you can do is giving the <label> an ID or class.

Comment: I think it's better to try other solutions (html structure) before resorting to jquery. You can not always solve everything with jquery especially for such nonsense.

Comment: I think he said it's a "bad solution" because that code alone won't do what OP is asking. It's definitely part of the solution, but OP might throw that code in a script tag and still think it's the wrong answer.

Comment: Mindexperiment : there might be a way to do it with CSS, I can't think of one off the top of my head, but if there is it might not work in all browsers. `IE`

Comment: @Mindexperiment: there is *no* way, at all, that this can be achieved with CSS (_unless the element you want to target is a later sibling, or descendant of a sibling, element. JQuery might be unnecessary, but JavaScript is absolutely necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. CSS alone won't be good for this, b4ttl3m4st3r was close I think. http://jsfiddle.net/a3v3x/

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    var color = this.checked ? "#f00" : "#000";
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("label[for='"+id+"']").css('color',color);
});
```